# Multiple databases with MagicalRecord or sync only part of database to iCloud

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data, magicalrecord

I am currently syncing my entire Core Data store to iCloud so that the same data is available on all of the users iOS devices. This is all set up using [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) by doing this:

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithiCloudContainer:@"xxxxxxx.com.mydomain.MyAppName" localStoreNamed:@"MyAppName"];
```

However, I would like to store some device specific entities in the database. It's basically used for caching information retrieved from the web and I don't want this to take up space on the users iCloud account.

I believe there would be two ways to do this:

1. Choose which tables of a database should be synchronized and ignore the tables used for device specific entities.
2. Have MagicalRecord manage multiple databases and store the entities which should be synchronized in one database and the device specific in the other.

I don't know if any of those two ways are possible or which would be the most simple to maintain and/or implement.

Does anyone know if this is possible and how it can be done? A code example would be greatly appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**

I am trying to follow the approach proposed by [casademora in the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14073041/486845) but when doing so both of my stores end up beign synced to iCloud. I have added the following in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithiCloudContainer:@"xxxxxxxxx.com.mydomain.MyAppName" localStoreNamed:@"MyAppName_iCloud"];
    [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator coordinatorWithInMemoryStore] addSqliteStoreNamed:@"MyAppName" withOptions:nil];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

I have added two data models to the project. One named *MyAppName_iCloud.xcdatamodeld* and one named *MyAppName.xcdatamodeld*.

I would like to avoid that the MyAppName store is synced to iCloud.

Comment: How much data is device-specific? It might be more trouble than it's worth to try to sync some data rather than all of it?

Comment: I have considered that. The device specific data is meant as a "cache" for data downloaded from a web service. When the device launches, I want to display this information while loading data from the web so that the user is not hindered in using the app while loading. Also, this is used for offline capabilities. It could be a lot of information but it probably isn't too bad. Honestly, I don't have an estimate on the amount of data yet and that's why I was looking to implement a more ideal solution. However, I might end up just syncing all of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MagicalRecord is merely a collection of useful helper methods that make CoreData easier to deal with. MagicalRecord is not a wrapper or a replacement for CoreData. This is key to understand that whatever CoreData can do, MagicalRecord can do. So, if CoreData can handle multiple persistent stores, MagicalRecord can as well. The only trick is to find the proper helper method that fits your needs. In this case, that method is in NSPersistentStoreCoordinator. Take a look at the -addSqliteStoreNamed: method. This will do what you need, without all the extra parameters of the regular addPersistentStore: method (which is actually used under the covers anyhow)

Comment: I'm glad to here that this is possible. I have tried to get this working but for some reason both of my stores end up being synced to iCloud. Would you mind taking a look on my approach to see if you know what is wrong? I have updated the original question to show my code.

Comment: Ideally the categories themselves have the instance variables which get set in course of initialization of the core data stack, hence it is more than the methods.