# Using magicalrecords library in custom static framework iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, frameworks, static-libraries, magicalrecord

I've been implementing a custom static framework for iOS. Everything is working well, but now I realized that I need a store information via coredata in the framework. I've been using the magicalrecord library with my previous projects and I was wondering if anyone has any experience integrating magicalrecord into your own custom static framework.

When ever I call the setupcorestack method inside my framework code nothing happens.

Comment: You are supplying the needed headers to your custom library/framework. Then, the app that uses your library/framework needs to link against all needed libraries/object-files/frameworks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how we've done it:

```
// 1: Note that all setup is done within the AppDelegate of the project (not the framework)

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    // 2: Locate your framework bundle
    NSString *mainBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSString *frameworkBundlePath = [mainBundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Your-Framework-Bundle-Name.bundle"];
    NSBundle *frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:frameworkBundlePath];

    // 3: Create an NSManagedObject Model by merging all models from the project and your framework. This simplifies saving as you can use a single persistent store coordinator to save a single managed object model.
    NSArray *bundles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSBundle mainBundle], frameworkBundle, nil];
    NSManagedObjectModel *models = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:bundles];

    [MagicalRecord setShouldAutoCreateManagedObjectModel:NO];
    [NSManagedObjectModel setDefaultManagedObjectModel:models];
    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"Your-Store-Name.sqlite"];

    // Project specific setup goes here...

    return YES;
    }
```

Note: it seems to be possible to have multiple persistent stores and multiple databases, but we haven't tried doing this or have had a need to as of yet. However, if you do need multiple persistent stores in your case, you might also refer to this other SO post:

[Multiple databases with MagicalRecord or sync only part of database to iCloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069730/multiple-databases-with-magicalrecord-or-sync-only-part-of-database-to-icloud)

Comment: Hi, the above solution is not working incase of cocoa-touch-framework.

Comment: This answer is nearly 3 years old... things may have changed with the current version of things... If you find a newer/better solution, feel free to post it as a new answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Comment: 4 years old but still accurate! What I was missing was:
`[MagicalRecord setShouldAutoCreateManagedObjectModel:NO];`
Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

I do it like this:

```
NSManagedObjectModel *model = [NSManagedObjectModel MR_newModelNamed:@"MyModel.momd" inBundleNamed:@"myOtherResource.bundle"];
[NSManagedObjectModel  MR_setDefaultManagedObjectModel:model];

//... continue to setup CoreDataStack after here
```